# Making ogr2ogr not normalize field names

Tags: ogr2ogr

I have a CSV file that I'm converting to Shapefile with the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=longitude -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=latitude  -f "ESRI Shapefile" output.shp input.csv
```

It successfully converts the file. However, I receive the following warning:

```
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'column_1' to 'column_'
```

In this example, `column_1` exists inside the CSV... Apparently, Shapefiles don't accept numbers in the field names, so it converts it to `column_`, but I'm not completely sure if that's the reason.

Is there any way to force `ogr2ogr` to not normalize field names?

I want to see in the Shapefile the field `column_1` exactly as it was originally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a wrong guess about what happens. Numbers are allowed in attribute names but they cannot be longer than 10 characters. I see that you did not use your real data in the example. "column_1" would not have suffered from laundering but there is no way to have longer than 10 chararters in the name. How GDAL renames attributes is documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html#creation-issues.

```
csvtest.csv
===========
id,column_1,longattributename
1,A,B

ogr2ogr csvtest.shp csvtest.csv
Warning 6: Normalized/laundered field name: 'longattributename' to 'longattrib'

ogrinfo csvtest.dbf -al -so
INFO: Open of `csvtest.dbf'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: csvtest
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2022-01-20
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
id: String (80.0)
column_1: String (80.0)
longattrib: String (80.0)
```